# How can I define the solution return as boolean?

Tags: java, junit

I wanna check if input was a Palindrome(reads the same way forward and backwards), But I am not familiar with Boolean. I do not know how to define a Boolean and return as a Boolean.

here is my test code

```
    @Test public void test5(){
    code.Solution s =  new code.Solution();
    String input = "dad ";
    int expected = true;
    int actual = s.is Palindrome(input);
    assert True("Expected was" +expected+"but the actual was" +actual  ,  expected == actual);
```

}

and I really do not know how to define my solution method.

Comment: `int expected = true;` will not compile. What does the implementation of your solution method look like now?

Comment: There is also a significant difference between Boolean and boolean

Answer (score 1):

Boolean datatype has only two states: true and false. Your isPalindrome function should return a boolean in the first place. Once it does the test will look like this:

```
boolean expected = true;
boolean actual = s.is Palindrome(input);
assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `assertEquals` method.

```
    @Test public void test5(){
    code.Solution s =  new code.Solution();
    String input = "dad ";
    boolean expected = true;
    boolean actual = s.is Palindrome(input);
    assertEquals(expected, actual);

    }
```

Also, change your expected and actual vairables to boolean instead of int.